# when completed with form on VB for excel my data doesnt get entered into excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have three forms.

- Form1(login)
- Form 2(informationAdd)
- Form 3(Information add to different sheet)

For some reason my macro is not entering my data into excel when I press submit for the third form.
My second form enters information but when entering the third form the information is no where to be found.

```
Private Sub cmdSubmit_Click()

'Dim iRow As Long
'Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Scrap")

'find first empty row in database
iRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1

'check for a part number
If Trim(Me.txtPress.Value) = "" Then
  Me.txtPress.SetFocus
  MsgBox "Please enter press scrap"
  Exit Sub
End If

'copy the data to the database
'use protect and unprotect lines,
'     with your password
'     if worksheet is protected
With ws
'  .Unprotect Password:="Password"

  .Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Me.txtDelam.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 2).Value = Me.txtCuts.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 3).Value = Me.txtBurns.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 4).Value = Me.txtDents.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 5).Value = Me.txtStaple.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 6).Value = Me.txtGlue.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 7).Value = Me.txtPress.Value

'  .Protect Password:="Password"
End With

'clear the data
Me.txtDelam.Value = ""
Me.txtCuts.Value = ""
Me.txtBurns.Value = ""
Me.txtDents.Value = ""
Me.txtStaple.Value = ""
Me.txtGlue.Value = ""
Me.txtPress.Value = ""
Me.txtPress.SetFocus

Unload Me



End Sub
```

Comment: are you sure the button on the Form3 you are clicking is tied to this macro: `cmdSubmit_Click`? I suspect it's not because the code itself looks okay given the little information you've given to go off. Make sure the name of your button is indeed `cmdSubmit`

Comment: have you tried to debug print the value of `iRow`?

Comment: It is named cmdSubmit..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you send all Form 2 textbox values to Form 3 ?

I tried this way.
You may be have this kind of code in your Form 2 :

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    ' I send the value from Form2 to Form3
    YourForm3.txtPress.Value = YourForm2.TextBox1.Value
    YourForm3.Show
    Unload Me

End Sub
```

In the next step, the Form3 is opened with the Form2 informations, I run your code and it's working.
To my test, I just modified your iRow variables to `iRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1`

Comment: Thank you!!!! the iRow worked. But now when I press submit the form stays open. I need it to close when pressing submit.

Comment: Just add the line code 'Unload Me' at the end of your submit sub to close the form.

Comment: Thank you for your help JC! I appreciate it!

Comment: Great ! Don't forget to accept my answer ;) https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers